# do I need a virtual function

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, inheritance

I've a base class as follows -

```
Class Base {

    int a;
    int b;
    someInfo c;

  public:
    void setInfo(someInfo);
    someInfo getInfo();
};
```

with `someInfo` defined as -

```
struct someInfo{
    std::string name;
    std::string school;
};
```

Now I've a child class as follows:

```
Class child: public Base{

    int e;
    int f;
    someMoreInfo g;

  public:
    void setInfo(someMoreInfo);
    someMoreInfo getInfo();
};
```

with `someMoreInfo` struct as -

```
struct someMoreInfo{
    someInfo i;
    int j;
};
```

Now when implementing `getInfo()` and `setInfo` of the child class, do I need to make the base class's respective function `virtual` and override them here? Because everyone is saying so and I have got no idea why should I do that and why this wouldn't work already, *since both are different set of functions, difference being in return value or that of parameter*.

Any help for this fellow confused student would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you want runtime polymorphism for a member function it needs to be `virtual`.

Comment: and signature must match: return type, parameter types and their order/qualifiers cannot be different between mother class and child class.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It happens when object slicing occurs, right? But if I'm getting an slice object with only remaining properties of Base class, why would I even want that `:|`. This is what I fail to understood and teacher won't answer this directly.

Comment: @hg_git _"It happens when object slicing occurs, right?"_ Not really.

Comment: Why do you expect the *return type* of a function to be part of overload resolution? (It isn't; and if you don't understand what I mean by "overload resolution," you will probably need to just read about that for a while before you can return to your original question.)

Comment: @KyleStrand I understand what overload resolution is. I've written in my ques - `since both are different set of functions, difference being in return value or that of parameter.`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well other than that, why would I want to override the functions.

Comment: Actually, that's precisely the sentence that made me think you *don't* understand overload resolution! But since you *are* familiar with the term, you should be able to answer my question: *why would the **return value** determine which function is called?*

Comment: Anyway, let's start with something that's actually *very surprising* about the way C++ works: when a derived class and a base class both implement functions with the same name, and the function isn't `virtual` in the base class, the function is *never* overloaded--it is simply *hidden*. So, for instance, given `void Base::foo(int)` and `void Derived::foo();`, a pointer to a `Derived` instance *can **never** * call `Base::foo(int)`.

Comment: Also, note that *overloading* and *overriding* **are not the same** (or in fact even very similar concepts). *Overriding* refers *only* to `virtual` function; *overloading* refers to functions with different signatures but the same name.

Comment: But since they're *different* functions, then **you're right**, you *don't* want function *overriding*, you want function *overloading*.

Comment: @KyleStrand I can definitely call the `void Base::foo(int)` from inside the `void Derived::foo()` since it inherits it. I can't think of a scenario where I would have to call Base class function directly from a pointer to Derived class :/

Comment: @hg_git No offense, but that's just because you aren't really used to using the language yet; trust me, that is *absolutely* something that's expected to be possible with `public` members. If `Base::foo` is only intended to be used within derived class implementations, it should be `protected`.

Comment: @KyleStrand none taken. I'm currently studying so I know my limits :). `Base::foo` might be usable by its own since `Base` objects would be created alongside `Derived` objects.  However could you provide a simple example that could convince me the above scenario is possible.

Comment: Start your compiler, and try it out. Try `Base b* = new child().` Then try to call both functions with and without virtual. This should cost you 5 minutes.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a different approach that *does* permit calling both functions `getInfo`, although I wouldn't necessarily *recommend* using that approach.

Comment: As for accessing base-class methods: a derived class *is-an* instance of the *base* class, so anything that `Base` exposes as a `public` member is something that programmers will expect to be an available part of the interface for the *derived* class as well. And note that my answer includes the line `pB->setInfo(si);`, which is an example of a function in the `Base` class being called from a pointer to the `Derived` class.

Comment: ....or, sorry, no, of course my example is of a `Base`-type pointer. But here's an example: `auto managed_derived = std::make_unique<Derived>(); managed_derived->setInfo(si);` If `Base::setInfo` has any usefulness, then it is of course useful regardless of the type of the pointer you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what you want is for your `Derived` class to support the following interface:

```
someInfo si;
someMoreInfo smi;
Base* pB = new Derived;

// Setting info
pB->setInfo(si);       // Set the `Base::c` member of `*pB`
pB->setInfo(smi);      // Set the `Derived::g` member of `*pB`

// Getting info
someInfo pB_si = pB->getInfo();   // Get  `Base::c` from `*pB`
someMoreInfo pB_smi = pB->getInfo();   // Get  `Derived::g` from `*pB`
```

#### Setting info: overloading

You're actually **correct** that you **don't** need `setInfo` to be `virtual`, because `Derived::setInfo` doesn't **replace** the `Base` method; **both** are supposed to be accessible.

Unfortunately, as I've noted in a comment, by default `Base::setInfo` gets **hidden** by `Derived::setInfo`, *regardless* of the signature (!). Yes, this is surprising behavior; Scott Meyers notes in *Effective C++* that this "surprises every C++ programmer the first time they encounter it" (Item 33 of the third edition).

Fortunately, the solution is simple. You need the `using` keyword:

```
Class child: public Base{

  // ... private members...

  public:
    using Base::setInfo;
    void setInfo(someMoreInfo);

  // .. rest of class...
};
```

This *exposes* the otherwise hidden name `Base::setInfo`, permitting overload resolution to happen as if *both* versions of `setInfo` were defined inside `Derived`.

#### Getting info: return-dependent overload resolution

C++ **does not support overloading on return types**. You can easily check this:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    int foo() { return 3; }
    double foo() { return 83.4; }
};
```

Clang gives the following error (which is much more helpful than the GCC error):

```
error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
```

Now, you might ask, "why not?" Indeed, I know of at least one language, Perl, that supports different behavior based on the "context" in which an expression is evaluated.

This is actually pretty confusing (at least for those who aren't fans of Perl, I guess). In general, programmers *don't* expect different functions to be called depending on the *context* in which the function is called. And there are many contexts that don't clearly indicate the expected return type:

```
std::cout << Foo().foo() << std::endl;  // AMBIGUOUS!
```

... so there is simply no solution: you *cannot* differentiate two functions merely in their return type. You *must* provide different names for the two functions.

**EDIT:** If you really want, you *could* return-by-reference-argument:

```
void Base::getInfo(someInfo& si)
{
    si = c;
}
void Derived::getInfo(someMoreInfo& smi)
{
    smi = g;
}
```

Here, overload-resolution will be applied by checking the type of the argument passed to `getInfo`, and no ambiguity is possible. This is one of the benefits of returning by reference-argument, though it's debatable whether this is a superior to simply naming these more explicitly (I think explicit names would be preferable, and I think most programmers would agree).